# Does chrome dev tools have anything similar to sublime text's snippets and tab triggers?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, code-snippets

When I'm writing code in sublime text, I have the ability to create "snippets" that I can "tabtrigger" into my code.

For example, If I'm writing some js code and I want to log something to the console, I created a snippet so that all I have to do is type "log" and hit tab. As soon as I hit tab console.log(); is inserted into my code. Google seems to have a different definition of snippets, and I was wondering if the described functionality is available when writing code directly in the dev tools source panel?

Answer (score 1):

I did not find this `Tab trigger` ability in Chrome but a way to simmulate this operation:

Using **[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)**

Run it after installing , and right click AutoHotKey in the taskbar corner -> `Edit This Script`

Add the following to the script files.

```
#IfWinActive Developer Tools - 
::ml::
SendInput {Raw}margin-left:10px;
return
```

write your own script like above, then save it and `Reload This Script`

Have fun!

More to say:

`#IfWinActive` means this part only applies to the current window whose name started with `Developer Tools -` .So if you want this script work, you shoul make the develop window seperated from the main Chrome window to have this window name.

`::ml::` defines the keys to trigger, the starting `::` means this is a word , which can only trigger when it is followed by a space key or an enter key or a tab key a semicolon key and so on. Otherwise it will soon output `margin-left:10px;` once you typed `ml` .

`SendInput` with `{Raw}` can avoid triggerring endless loop. eg. bb -> border-bottom:1px solid #bbb; the output is ended with `bb;` and AutoHotKey will auto minimize the current window to avoid endless loop.